# Iterate over all nodes in a recursively defined tree

Tags: java, recursion

I am trying to make a node class that I will eventually be able to use for a minimax search, however I am having trouble iterating over all of the nodes in my tree  (in this case for a simple to string function).

Here is the definition of the recursive to string method.

```
    public String toString(){
        if(!this.isLeaf()){
            String text = "";
            Iterator<Node<T>> iter = children.iterator();
            while(iter.hasNext()){
                    Node child = iter.next();
                    text = "/" + child.toString();
            }
            return text;
        }else{

            return cargo.toString() ;
        }
    }
```

After reading other answers I tried using the Iterator interface as seen in the code above but it still didn't work. (I'm also open to non-recursive methods of doing this)

Comment: So you are trying to find the max of the tree? or just visit every node once? any particular order to visiting the nodes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume that you intended to concatenate the child values separated by a '/' as per tom's answer.

If you intend to build up a string, it is more efficient to use a StringBuffer, because otherwise each time around the loop a new String has to be allocated to take the new value, whereas a StringBuffer builds up in a buffer.

```
StringBuffer text = new StringBuffer();

for (Node<T> child : children) {
  text.append('/');
  text.append(child.toString());
}
return text.toString;
```

I've used a for-each style loop but the 'while' loop you used would still work as well.

Answer (score 2):

Did you mean `+=`?

```
text += "/" + child.toString();
     ^
```